# Apache start error: Cannot load libphp5.so

Tags: ubuntu, apache-http-server

I'm getting the following error when trying to start [Apache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_HTTP_Server) on an [Ubuntu 10.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Ubuntu_10.04_LTS_.28Lucid_Lynx.29) LTS (Lucid Lynx) vserver:

```
apache2: Syntax error on line 204 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax 
error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.load: Cannot load 
/usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so into server: /lib/libz.so.1: version 
`ZLIB_1.2.3.3' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2)
```

What does this mean? How do I fix this?

Comment: How did you install your apache2? With an apt-get? The dependencies should be resolved at installation time. Did you change the config etc.?
If it's a possibility for you, purging and reinstalling apache2 would be my first guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reinstalling `libxml2` solved my problem:

```
apt-get purge libxml2
apt-get install libxml2
```

After that I needed to install php5 again.

Comment: In my case there were a lot of system dependencies dependent on this package, include gnome desktop. So I would not purge this package.

Answer (score 1):

It means that apache is trying to Load the PHP5 module and failing.  PHP5 depends on the `libxml2` library, which in turns depends on `zlib` (v1.2.3.3), but it was unable to find `libz`.  Make sure you have `zlib` installed, on my Ubuntu system I would run:

```
sudo apt-get install zlib1g
```

Or if you're not using PHP5 run

```
sudo a2dismod php5
```

to disable that module.

Comment: It says `zlib1g is already the newest version.`